# Recovering a sharp estimate using Gronwall lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE:
$$
\dot x = - x + \varepsilon  \, e^{-2 t},
$$
where $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x, v \in \mathbb R^n$.
The solution (which can be obtained by the variation-of-constants formula) is given by
$$
x(t) = x(0) e^{- t} + \varepsilon (1 - e^{-  t}) e^{- t},
$$
and so $|x(t)| \leq (|x(0)| + \varepsilon) e^{- t}$.
I am trying to get to this inequality from an application of Gronwall's lemma (although, in the simplified version of the problem I present here, Gronwall's lemma is not needed).
Taking the product with $x$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2} \, \frac{d}{dt} |x|^2 = - x^2 + \varepsilon \, e^{-2 t} x.
$$
Using the variation-of-constants formula
$$
x^2 = e^{-2t} x(0)^2 +  2 \varepsilon \, e^{-2t} \int_{0}^{t} x(s) \, d s.     \quad \quad (1)
$$
Taking for granted that $x$ is bounded from above by a constant $C = O(1)$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$,
we deduce
$$
x^2 \leq C e^{-2t} (x(0)^2 +  \varepsilon t).
$$
Employing this bound in $(1)$,
and Young's inequality, we have (using the notation $C$ for any constant that is $O(1)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$)
\begin{align}
    x^2 &\leq e^{-2t} x(0)^2 +  C \varepsilon \, e^{-2t} \int_{0}^{t} e^{-s} (x(0) + \sqrt{\varepsilon s} ) \, d s \\
    &\leq e^{-2t} x(0)^2 +  C \varepsilon \, e^{-2t} (|x(0)| + \sqrt{\varepsilon}) \\
    &\leq e^{-2t} x(0)^2 +  C e^{-2t} (x(0)^2 + \varepsilon^{3/2}) \\
    &\leq C \, e^{-2t} (x(0)^2 + \varepsilon^{3/2}).
\end{align}
Employing this bound in $(1)$ again,
we can further refine the bound:
\begin{align}
    x^2 &\leq e^{-2t} x(0)^2 +  C \varepsilon \, e^{-2t} (x(0) + \varepsilon^{3/4}) \\
        &\leq C \, e^{-2t} (x(0)^2 + \varepsilon^{7/4}).
\end{align}
Repeating the same reasoning, 
we can show that there is $C = C(n)$ ($= O(1)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$) such that 
$$
|x(t)| \leq C \, e^{-t} (|x(0)| + \varepsilon^{\frac{2^{n} - 1}{2^n}}).
$$
We know, however, that this inequality is also true when the exponent of $\varepsilon$ is exactly 1,
which leads to my question: is it possible to recover the accurate bound (with the power of $\varepsilon$ equal to 1) from (1)?

Comment: I guess this could work, although this would require to show that $C(n)$ is bounded from above as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Consider $x(t) = e^{-t} (\varepsilon^2 \, \log(1/\varepsilon))$, which illustrates why the limiting procedure is not rigorous.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I corrected.